# How can I differentiate 2 triggers in script?

Tags: unity

I have two boxcolliders with triggers, and when I use the function OnTriggerEnter, even if I enter the first or the second trigger, it does the same thing. And I want a trigger to do a certain thing and the other to do another thing. How can I differentiate that 2 triggers?

Comment: I've tried with name tags. And it didn't work, or I didn't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do so is to,

- Create 2 children gameObject of your object.
- Attach one collider to each child.
- Set tags for each collider. For example "Left" and "Right"
- Attach your script to both children.
- In script, check the tag first. Like,

  ```
  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
      if (tag == "Left"){
          print("Collided with left");
      }
      else if (tag == "Right"){
          print("Collided with right");
      }
  }
  ```

Or you can use switch case instead of if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible without using child objects, although trickier.

You would need to differentiate your colliders by something *other than* the GameObject's properties.  That is: the collider properties.

If you have two colliders that cover a different volume, then one of their position or size properties is different than the other.  You can use this to figure out which collider was triggered.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
   //arbitrary bounds determination, your setup may be different
   if (col.bounds.center.x < 0){
       Debug.Log("Collided with left");
   } else if (col.bounds.center.x > 0){
       Debug.Log("Collided with right");
   }
}
```