# Differentiate between Triggers in OnTriggerEnter Unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I want to implement a simple functionality in my Unity application:

- I have a water volume represented by a Tilemap with TilemapCollider2D.
- I have a player that has 2 triggers: 1 in the center of the body, 1 at the bottom.
- I want to use the bottom trigger to create a water splash effect once the player enters the water.
- I want to use the central trigger to detect that the player is in the water. I can't use the bottom one because I need to set gravity to 0 in water and if I do it using the bottom collider, the player will stand on water.

[image: My setup]

With all that said I want to differentiate between those 2 colliders in OnTriggerEnter2D method of my player's object. I haven't found a good way to do it so far. I know this question was asked many times but maybe things changed in the last versions of Unity.

Comment: Does these past Q&A threads answer your question? [How can I differentiate 2 triggers in script?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116017/39518) / [How to know which child collider triggered in parent?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172652/39518)

Comment: Even though this solution isn't ideal, I ended up placing triggers on different child objects of the main object, each with separate scripts. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't allow for handling trigger events on the main object, as it would catch all collisions from the child colliders. But it is what it is; it seems handling this situation in Unity is still not so straightforward. Thanks for the provided links!

Comment: It does allow for that. You just have your child scripts call a custom `OnTriggerEnter2D(child, other)` method with their identifying details.

Comment: You can move the "main" collider to a third child and differentiate between all of them.